# Protocol Buffer - assign nested message

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, grpc

My PB Schema looks like below:

```
message ProductRecommendationReply {
  string productid = 1;
  message recommendationlist{
    string recommendedproductid = 1;
    string recommendedproductname = 2;
    string recommendedproductprice = 3;
  }
}
```

At the server side (node.js), I am trying to set the properties like below:

```
var message = {
            productid: '',
            recommendationlist: []
        };
        message.productid = result_list.product_Id;
        message.recommendationlist.recommendedproductid = result_list.recomendation_list[0].recommended_product_id;
        message.recommendationlist.recommendedproductname = result_list.recomendation_list[0].recommended_product_name;
        message.recommendationlist.recommendedproductprice = result_list.recomendation_list[0].recommended_product_price;

        callback(null,message); // send the result back to consumer.
```

The problem is when debugging the clinet side, only the `productid` has a value assigned to it, the `recommendationlist` is empty.

How can I properly assign a value to the nested message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a message but didn't declare a field of that message type. I think you mean to do

```
message ProductRecommendationReply {
  string productid = 1;
  message productrecommendationlist {
    string recommendedproductid = 1;
    string recommendedproductname = 2;
    string recommendedproductprice = 3;
  }
  repeated productrecommendationlist recommendationlist = 2;
}
```

Comment: having "repeated" type on "recommendationlist" was very important. otherwise the array won't work.